# `fopen` does not return NULL but did not open the file either

Tags: c, io

I have been running the same code for quite some time and this morning `fopen` failed. I have a simple check where if the pointer returned by `fopen` is `NULL` I conclude that the file was not opened successfully as per the description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.90).aspx

The calling code in the project:

```
return fopen(a_fileName, "r"); // expected return to be NULL if the file can't be opened
```

Although at this point I can check `errno` but since the code is cross-platform, I am not sure whether I can rely on `errno`. But back to the original problem, why is `fopen` *not* returning `NULL`? See a screenshot below of *Visual C++ debugger*.

[image]

Note that the file actually exists but for some reason (which I am investigating now - decided to post this question before going ahead to see what the problem is as I may not be able to reproduce it) `fopen` fails to open the file. But again, why doesn't it return `NULL`?

If this is normal behaviour, should I then write:

```
if (retFilePtr != NULL && retFilePtr->_ptr != NULL) 
{
  // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: If it does not return NULL, how do you know it failed? To me, it seems to be successful. Maybe you can post your *real* problem?

Comment: As for the errno thing, you can use ferrer(), which is standard C http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ferror/

Comment: No, you should not refer to internal FILE's members. Show your code and give more details if possible.
What happens when you try to read or write this file?

Comment: `fopen` thinks the file is empty. You are right, I do not know that it failed. The file exists, other files in the same folder open perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, I agree with @nvoigt... I think you shouldn't touch the _ptr member of the FILE structure, because it's internal implementation. Maybe it lazy-opens the file on first access? (I doubt it, but still)

Comment: From the linked page:  "Each of these functions returns a pointer to the open file. A null pointer value indicates an error".  Given that, a non-NULL return value means fopen() succeeded.  (or that there is a bug, but it seems unlikely that there is a bug in fopen())

Comment: Looks like a successful `fopen` to me -- `_ptr` being null just means that you haven't yet read any data from the file, and no data has been pulled into the buffer either.  That will happen the first time you try to read from the `FILE`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I agree, it is highly unlikely `fopen` has a bug. I am investigating the problem now to see why other files in the same folder are opening fine. There don't appear to be any locks on the file (not sure how `fopen` behaves there?) and I can open it fine in notepad.

Comment: A rebuild of the library and the project 'fixed' the issue. Not sure what to make of it. Not sure how to reproduce it.

Comment: Your `fopen` call succeeded. The only mystery is why you think it failed. The members of the `FILE` type are internal; do not assume anything about their meanings. What exactly led you to conclude that the file was not successfully opened?

Comment: What happens if you call fread() or fwrite() on the file in the case you described? Does it succeed or fail? Did you check that? Or did you stop after fopen() because you thought you found the problem?

Comment: @WernerHenze: I did not check that. I stopped after `fopen` assuming it had failed (incorrect assumption). It is fine with a rebuild. Not sure how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can believe it's fine after a rebuild. I think it was also fine *before* the rebuild. Your call to `fopen()` returned a non-null result. Why exactly did you think it had failed? If your only basis for that is that the internal members of the `FILE` object had values you didn't expect, that means nothing. (I don't mean to beat a dead horse, but it would be nice if this question could be useful for future readers; as it stands, I see no indication that there was ever a real problem.)

Comment: One possible explanation:  before the rebuild, an out-of-date object file was being used, causing data to be written to the wrong location, which in turned cause the symptoms that prompted this Question to be posted.  Mismatched object files can cause all kinds of odd misbehavior... :(

Comment: @KeithThompson: I didn't immediately jump to the posted code. The file was _read_ but was empty which caused some assertions to fire elsewhere. Upon investigation it turned out that `fopen` was returning successful but the contents were empty even though the file existed, paths were correct, and other files in the same folder loaded properly. My original assumptions were incorrect as I assumed `fopen` had failed which lead to the question. Hopefully this thread will help a future SOer dismiss `fopen` as a possible cause and look elsewhere for the bug.

Comment: Just to state the obvious -- you say the file existed. I presume you also verified that the file was not empty? The original behavior you described is consistent with successfully opening a file that exists but has no contents.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, I opened it up in notepad to verify that the file did indeed exist. I went a step further and opened it in a project I created from scratch after which I rebuild the main library (which takes quite a white to compile hence my apprehension to rebuild - learned the lesson ;) and the current project which fixed the problem.

Comment: You didn't quite answer the question I asked. A file can *exist* and be empty. Did you verify that the file existed *and was not empty*?

Comment: @KeithThompson: It was not empty :) I opened it in notepad for that very purpose, to check whether it was empty or not because the file clearly existed in the folder. That is what started my line of reasoning and considering (incorrectly) that `fopen` was not opening the file correctly but saying it did.

Comment: Is the file text or binary? If it's binary, you need to use the mode `"rb"`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40286/discussion-between-samaursa-and-keith-thompson)